# iOS: 3D rotation view for Web app to support on Mobiles as well

Tags: ios, web-applications

I am trying to build a web app similar to 
http://www.nissanusa.com/electric-cars/leaf/colors-photos/#_interior
Advantage with is, it works both on iPad browser and Web based as well?
I would like to know how i can achieve this? Looks like, they have used 3D rotation, if that is the case, what is the possibility for me to develop such the same.
I would request could someone please advise me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just uses 13 images, and change them when you drag adding or substracting 1 to the image name depending on the drag direction. The first one is 00.jpg and goes up to 12.jpg

Comment: OK.So, it can be done like this HTML itself? Is that not real 3d or 2d rotation?

Comment: Yes, the example on your link is just that, 13 images that change the <img> src while you drag the finger over the image. It's not real 3D, but doesn't look bad